# Android: Correct way to use a Service in a multi-Activity application

Tags: java, android, service

I know, that there are tons of questions regarding leaking Android services and how to "maintain" a service in an app, but it's a bit like seeing two doctors with one problem: you get three different opinions...

In other words: I am completely unsure, how to deal with my service in a proper way. Hence this question.

I have the following: Several `Activities` and a `BoundService`, which is started on app startup and should be kept alive until the app closes.

Android.delevoper proposes to use a bound service to ease communication between `Service` and `Activity`. So I bind my service in each activitie's `onStart()` and unbind it in every `onStop()` to keep it from leaking.

In addition, I read in several threads, that one should use startService() to keep the service from being destroyed when no Activity is binding to it anymore. So I use an explicit `startService()` in my first `Activity` and a `stopService()` on every exit point of my app.

So basically I have this as my `Service`:

```
public class NetworkService extends Service {
    private final IBinder binder = new ServiceBinder();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
        public NetworkService getService() {
            return NetworkService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

And then a starting Activity like this:

```
public class ActFirstActivity extends Activity {
    private NetworkService      networkService;
    private boolean             networkServiceIsBound   = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, NetworkService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);
        bindService(serviceIntent, networkServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unbindService(networkServiceConnection);
    }

    private ServiceConnection networkServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            ServiceBinder binder = (ServiceBinder) service;
            networkService = binder.getService();
            networkServiceIsBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            networkServiceIsBound = false;
        }
    };
}
```

Every other `Activity` would have the same bind/unbind functionality and the same `ServiceConnection`. As far as I can see, this keeps my app from leaking a service connection. But I have the impression that I introduced a LOT of overhead here. How to do this

- a) secure (no leaking),
- b) efficient (minimal overhead), and
- c) easy to maintain (code-wise) ?

Thanks to everyone who takes the time to answer :)

Comment: ad b) instead of pair resume/pause use start/stop events of your Activity

Comment: won't this cause the service to leak if onPause() gets called and the Activity is halted and then destroyed (e.g. due to ressource shortage)?

Comment: if it is destroyed so who cares?  see:  http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html section **Additional notes**

Comment: ok thanks - code in thread edited accordingly